# storyboard content hides after sometime - iOS, swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

Hello, fellow developers.
I am using latest Xcode - 9.2 and in this facing an issue related to storyboard. I create multiple storyboards and View Controllers in it.
The content of View Controllers comes blank when I restart my Xcode the problem seems to go away. (It's happening continuously, and its difficult to work, when not able to set the content).

****In the attached picture, my view controllers contains multiple views but showing blank. *******

please help me, if someone knows, what the actual problem is.
Is it Xcode bug or anything?

Comment: How many ViewControllers do you have in your storyboard?

Comment: This is an error with Xcode (one of many). I stumble upon it once in a while. as you mentioned restarting Xcode seems to be the only solution

Comment: This isnt a bug. Do you have labels in your view controller?

Comment: @akshansh thakur
i do have labels, buttons with different color. Firstly they work fine, but after 2-3 hours of working this problems appears.

Comment: @karthick
i only have 5-6 view controllers in my storyboards.
max 8

Comment: @giorashc
yeah, after restart it works fine for half hour.
then it need to restart again.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that the color of your images and the background color are the same.
In order to check this, set the background color, for example green.

Comment: the color of images, buttons or any views are different, but only white appears.
and as i mentioned, after restarting it works normal for some time.
i am not that stupid :P 
so, please if you have any valid reason or solution then provide me.